# How to interactively choose the size (in inch) while exporting plots in RStudio?

Tags: r, pdf, plot, rstudio

In Rstudio, if I choose `Export as an Image`, an interactive window pops up that allows me to interactively resize the plot and shows me the size in pixels before saving. This is very convenient, but not reproducible.

On the other hand, if I do `pdf("plot.pdf", width = 1, height = 1)` or similarly `ggsave()`, it's reproducible, but not very convenient since I have to guess how my plot looks.

Is there a way to interactively resize the plot in RStudio and see the size in inches, which then can be used in `pdf()` or `ggsave()`?

Comment: maybe you're looking for `dev.size()`.

Comment: I find that using something like SumatraPDF (which can update on the fly) basically accomplishes what you are looking for. Then you can tweak the size arguments, re-run the code, switch over to the Sumatra window, see if worked and repeat if needed.

Comment: Exactly what I need! @feats-by-jake